# Error 128 al tratar de instalar un repositorio con npm

Tags: nodejs, npm, ssh, gitlab

Descargue el repositorio con el que voy a trabajar y en el package.json quiero instalar un repositorio privado de Gitlab y me muestra el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Bec\Documents\Bec\Soft\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@gitlab.com/xxxx/xxxxx.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bec\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-01T20_48_33_984Z-debug.log
```

Tengo mi clave ssh enlazada con Gitlab y tengo los permisos para ver el repositorio privado.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que di a este problema fué ejecutando directamente el agente con el siguiente comando:

```
start-ssh-agent
```

Posteriormente instalé el repositorio:

```
npm i git+http://gitlab.com/[group]/[repo].git
```